# Customize Alarm In Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I know that very well there is not property for tap on alarm to navigate to Specific Page.But a application available in windows phone store ([Alarm plus](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/store/app/alarms-plus/7b5ed0f1-bbc3-4d9f-8974-732d982dfe6a)). This application navigate to specific page by alarm if Windows phone unlock.Please suggest me how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alarms do not support setting a title or the NavigationUri

[See some info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.scheduler.alarm%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

it specifically says:

This class inherits from ScheduledNotification and ScheduledAction. The title displayed in the alarm dialog is always “Alarm”. To create a notification that can pass contextual information to the application that created it, use Reminder.

I suggest you use a reminder instead, which also inherits from the ScheduledNotification base class.

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.scheduler.reminder%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

[image]

Comment: But a application available in windows phone store (Alarm plus).In the application alarm worked on navigation uri.

Comment: Are you referring to this app? http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=7b5ed0f1-bbc3-4d9f-8974-732d982dfe6a  the screenshot above is what I see when you set an alarm.

Comment: Yes. But this application you can tap on alarm popup. Popup navigate on landing page if device is unlock.

Comment: Just tested this, I don't have this behaviour, either from the home screen or the lock screen...

Comment: I am the dev of 'Alarms plus' app, this behavior used to work prior to WP8, but not any more. Even in WP7.5/7 you can not specify the page, it only goes to the start page, there you can have your logic to redirect to the required page(that's what the app do).